# Is there an Equivalent scanf function in Lua?

Tags: c, lua, scanf

As the title said:

Is there an Equivalent scanf function in Lua?

I mean, I want to have a syntax like this:

```
word_typed = lua_scanf()
```

Once I have written a string(let's say "123 is perfect number"), I have the string "123 is perfect number".

Many thanks in advance

P.S. You can give, if you want, a LUA C API solution if you want!! :P

Comment: search this page for `io.read`: http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html do you mean something like that?

Comment: io.read takes from the io.stdin its argument! In the file I wrote I have io.stdin occupied by a file in reading mode. I copy it on an file in write mode but when it encounter a certain line, I want to visualize it anchange iy with a scanf-like function. Is the explanation clear?

Comment: Simply DON'T open another file in a way that it replaces the default input file (that is, don't use io.input), but rather store the handle yourself (that is, do use io.open).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following script (tested with Lua 5.1.4, *should work in 5.2*) does what you describe in your comment to Shmil-The-Cat's answer:

```
print("Please enter your name:")
name = io.read()
print("You entered '" .. name .. "'")
```

The `io.read` function has a default parameter of `"*l"` which means to read the next line from the open file, skipping the end of line.  The open file, by default is `stdin` but you can change it using the `io.open` file.

For more details on the `io` library, see section 6.8 of the online Lua reference manual, which can be found at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.8.  You might also want to read the I/O chapter of *Programming in Lua* (PIL) which can be found at http://www.lua.org/pil/21.html.

Comment: The problem is that if I have stdin occupied with a file in reading mode, io.read reads the next line of that file and it doesn't take my inline input! Right?

Comment: You can read from more than one file by using the io.read function in an object-oriented fashion, i.e. if `file1` and `file2` are open file objects, you can call `file1:read()` and `file2:read()`.  But if you have redirected another file onto `stdin`, then you won't be able to accept terminal input unless you close the file and redirect stdin to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`match` http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial seems to me close to C scanf

Comment: I want that the scripting running stops, I enter the string and Lua ends the computation!

I don't insert the string in the script